# Admin and user functionalities in the same android app?

Tags: android, security, design-patterns

I'm creating an android app which in theory has 2 types or users: admin(providers) and customers(users). So that the user interacts with what the admin provides. Also, I want the providers to see stats and modify their products through a panel which can only be accessed by them. So I was wondering:

Should I join both features in the same app and add some authentication or should I separate these apps and make the admin app a private option on play store and give them privately to admins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should join both functions in the app and provide user an option for choosing between being a provider or user, during register and login activity and then they can have different interfaces, this will help them migrate from user to provider or provider to user easily, and it is also the way most apps are designed.

Comment: yep I understand but my problem was in the long-run perspective. If my app grows large, I thought it will lead to security issues(any person can just came and  just create a providers account which may leave the database full of useless and fake providers account who provide fake things). what do you think please?

Comment: I understand your problem, but it also depends upon the industry i feel, and on how easy is it to make a provider account, if for example you are providing it for e-commerce, true that a lot of people would be making provider accounts to sell goods, but then if making a provider accounts require a lot of documents not most of people would make it, so therefore it is a subjective question.